# Problem with importing tensorflow and testing NN

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network, importerror

I'm currently working on a program to play a game similar to atari-games. I'm using keras (python 3). I finished writing the code and I want to test it, and I have few questions about the process:
first of all, I have trouble importing tesnorflow for some reason. I've installed it using pip. I've made sure to created new env. before the installation (which finished successfully), but when I try to run my program it says:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
```

I also, tried to install the package from within pycharm, but then I get this error:

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tensorflow
```

I've checked program requirements (such as pip, python, virtualenv and setuptools versions) and everything seems up to date. perhaps someone could point out what else might be the problem?

Is there any other way I can test the performance of my program?

Thank you very much for your time and attention.

Answer (score 0):

**Anaconda** is a complete time-saver. I suggest create an enviornment using Anaconda and install the tensorflow by `conda install tensorflow` If you would like to use the gpu version, conda automatically installs the CUDA and cudnn for you too.

Comment: thanks for the response, I've tried it already and it didn't work either. someone told me to check if I can find tensorflow in the output of jupitenotebook using the command pip freeze and I couldn't but I don't understand how to correct it. perhaps you have any idea what can I do to make it work? perhaps I need to upgrade something?

Comment: I will list some options to try with.

**1)** Try `--ignore-installed` flag with pip.

**2)** install from a `.whl` _i.e_ try building from source.

**3)** Uprgrade your pip version.

**4)** Try `Anaconda Navigator`

**5)** Check your Python version. It needs to be 64bit, if it's 32bit, just replace with a 64bit one.

**6)** First `activate your_env` and then use `pip list` to ensure it is installed.

Comment: thank you for your help. I've checked and my python version was 3.7.3 (I thought I downgraded it but apparently I didn't) and after changing it to 3.6.0 it finally worked. Thanks once again!